# Merge via pandas vs. Join via SQL memory usage and speed

Tags: sql, pandas, sqlite

I have an SQLite file with two tables. One of these tables is pretty large, but when I use `pd.read_sql_table` on this, `df.info()` only gives a memory usage of ~4GB. The other table uses even less memory.

However, when I try to merge these two tables on two columns via an SQL query, and then read the resulting query by pandas via `pd.read_sql_query`, I get to use much, much larger memory and it's even slower, too.

```
query = '''SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,colC FROM
            (SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on (table1.col1 = table2.colA AND table1.col2 = table2.colB)'''
df = pd.read_sql_query(query)
```

I find this surprising since I thought doing things via SQL would be faster. Is it the way that I do it, or could this be a machine-dependent issue?

Comment: If you want us to compare two pieces of code, show us the code *(rather than just notional descriptions)*

Comment: Hi @MatBailie edited my question above to show the code.

Comment: Are you ***certain*** that `table1(col1,col2)` is unique ***or*** that `table2(colA, colB)` is unique?  If both are not unique you will cause duplication.  Try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1` and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2` and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourQuery` to see if you're causing duplication.  Try `SELECT cardinality, SUM(cardinality) AS row_count FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cardinaility FROM table1 GROUP BY col1, col2) AS summary GROUP BY cardinality ORDER BY cardinality` to check uniqueness in table1...

Comment: Also, be certain you have appropriate indexes on the tables to make the joins are faster.  Even if that's just primary keys on `table1(col1,col2)` and `table2(colA, colB)`

Comment: No, they are not unique...in a  sense that there are several rows in `table1` corresponding to some `(col1,col2)` value. However, in `table2`, there is only *one* row corresponding to the same pair (but now `col1,col2` are called `colA,colB`), and I'm interested in having `colC` (see edited code above) mixed in the merge. All unique pairs in `col1,col2` are in `colA,colB`.

Comment: That they're unique in one table *(`table2`)* is enough to prevent duplication.  Are there any indexes or primary keys, on either take? Are their any foreign key constrains on `table1`?

Comment: No indices though. The "indices" are basically `col1` and `col2` with corresponding columns in `colA` and `colB`.

Comment: Add a primary key on `Table2(colA, colB)`, it will help the join go faster.  And if you also add an index `Table1(Col1, Col2)` it may go faster again still *(because now the indices are in the same order on both tables)*.

Comment: I'll see if I can do that, thanks!